# How to group results into array based on multiple similar values, Django Model

Tags: django

I have an array as follows:

```
    [
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToCustomer",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 3,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 3,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 4,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 4,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 5,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T16:22:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 5,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:23:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 6,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 6,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 1,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 1,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T05:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T15:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "PM",
    "DaysToAdd": 0,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T17:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "WarehouseId": 2,
    "ShippingCarrierId": 2,
    "PostalCodeType": "ShipToDS",
    "TimeStart": "1970-01-01T16:00:00.000Z",
    "TimeEnd": "1970-01-01T23:59:00.000Z",
    "PickupTimeSlot": "AM",
    "DaysToAdd": 1,
    "PickupTime": "1970-01-01T11:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I want to group it by WarehouseId, ShippingCarrierId and PostalCodeType. Each object will have child array of objects for Timestart, TimeEnd etc

How can I achieve this result:

PickupTimeTable: [{
WarehouseId: 1,
ShippingCarrierId: 1,
PostalCodeType: 'ShipToCustomer',
PickupTimeSlots: [{
StartTime: '06:00:00.0000000',
EndTime: '15:59:00.0000000',
Slot: 'PM',
PickupTime: '17:00:00.0000000',
DaysToAdd: 0
},
{
StartTime: '16:00:00.0000000',
EndTime: '23:59:00.0000000',
Slot: 'AM',
PickupTime: '11:00:00.0000000',
DaysToAdd: 1
},
{
StartTime: '00:00:00.0000000',
EndTime: '05:59:00.0000000',
Slot: 'AM',
PickupTime: '11:00:00.0000000',
DaysToAdd: 0
},
]
}, ]

Comment: I suggest that you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple data aggregation.

```
data = [{...}]  # This is the first data you get from database.

result = dict()
for item in data:
    group_by_str = f"{item['WarehouseId']}-{item['ShippingCarrierId']}-{item['PostalCodeType']}"
    if group_by_str in result:
        result[group_by_str]['PickupTimeSlots'].append({"StartTime": item['StartTime'], ...})
    else:
        result[group_by_str] = {"WarehouseId": item['WarehouseId'], "ShippingCarrierId": item['ShippingCarrierId'], "PostalCodeType": item['PostalCodeType'], 'PickupTimeSlots': [{"StartTime": item['StartTime'], ...}]}

result = list(result.values())
```

I didn't fully put the fields but I think you can continue from that.

Comment: I don't understand a single thing from your comment. Maybe edit your question and show what's the data you have, what's the final output you expect and then we can help you?

Comment: ok but Cagatay barin i got answer from you given example code...Thank you so much